# Skip first character from CSV file in Oracle sql loader control file

Tags: oracle, csv, file, controls, sql-loader

How do I skip the first character?
Here is the CSV file that I want to load

```
H
B"01","Mosco"
B"02","Delhi"
T
```

Here is the control file

````
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'capital.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE CAPITALS
WHEN (01)='B'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
ID,
CAPITAL
)```

WHEN i RUN THIS THE 'B' COMES INTO PICTURE.
The table should look like
[![Table view][1]][1]

How do I skip the 'B'?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U3Vo.png
````

Comment: What exactly do you want to load into the table? You posted INPUT; please, post desired OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard the first character.  Can you have the source put a comma after the record type indicator?

If so, do this to ignore it:

```
(
RECORD_IND FILLER,
ID,
CAPITAL
)
```

If not, this should take care of it in your situation:

```
ID "SUBSTR(:ID, 2)",
```